# Problemas para entender la lògica del FOR

Tags: javascript, html, bucle-for, bucles

Estoy haciendo una linea de ejercicios de un libro de js y ahora voy por la parte de bucles que crei que dominadaba porque pude hacer una tabla con los datos que querias y cantidad de columnas y filas que el usuario queria pero luego me da el codigo de un for que dibuja figuras usando "*" y resulta que no logro entender la logica y llevo 4 dias sin entender y me gustaria entender porque lo hace asi, he aqui el còdigo:

`````
<head><meta charset="utf-8"/>
<style>
   
</style>
<script>
let fila;
let columna = parseInt(prompt("Introduce el tamaño: ", "0"))
for (fila = 1; fila <= columna; fila++){
   for (espacios = columna - fila; espacios > 0; espacios--)
       document.write("&nbsp&nbsp");
   for (conta = 1; conta < (2 * fila); conta++)
       document.write("*");
       document.writeln("</br>");
}
</script>
</head>
</html>````

<!--Este es el código del libro y en base a eso me dice que tengo que hacer diferentes figuras, lo que quiero es entenderlo para poder hacer el código yo, desde ya gracias por su atención-->
`````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El primer for empieza con la fila 1 y termina hasta llegar al número solicitado, es esta caso la variable "columna"

El segundo for, que esta dentro del primero, calcula los espacios, la variable espacios es la diferencia entre el valor digitado menos la fila en la que esta. Como empieza en la primer fila esta tendra (columna - 1 = N espacios), la segunda parte del for es una condicion, dice que en cuando la variable espacios llegue a cero el ciclo termina, la variable espacios se le decrementa de 1 en 1 para ir "pintando" cada uno de los espacios.

la lógica de los espacios es la siguiente:
se da un valor a "columna" por ejemplo el 3
si vemos que en el primer for empieza de 1 hasta llegar a 3.

cuando el ciclo llega a la fila 1 y empieza el segundo for entonces necesitamos N espacios en esa fila, que son (3 - 1 = 2) y pinta los espacios:

__

en la siguiente fila seria (3 - 2 = 1): (ya con la primer fila pintada)

__
_
en la ultima secuencia los espacios serian (3 - 3 = 0) y no pinta nada.

lo hace asi para de alguna manera centrar el asterisco de la primer fila y extenderse a los lados, es por eso que siempre son cantidad de asteriscos impar.

El tercer for empieza a escribir los asteriscos.Empieza con tener un asterisco y en la condicion esta diseñada para contar los dos asteriscos extra que se van a ir poniendo conforme baje en las filas.
En la fila 1 empieza con 1 asterisco, la condicion pregunta si conta es menor que el doble de la fila en la que esta, si es la primer file seria (conta < 2 * 1) es decir si conta empieza en 1 el intervalo de valores que cumple conta va desde 1 hasta (conta < 2 * 1), es decir, el valor maximo de conta es 1 y entonces pinta un asterisco, y manteniendo los espacios queda asi:

__X
en la segunda fila pinta el espacio para que los asteriscos queden "centrados",
la variable conta empieza con 1, y termina hasta donde (conta < 2 * 2), entonces el rango de valores de conta va de 1 hasta 3, por lo que son tres asteriscos, y se ve asi:

__X
_XXX
a cada fila le quita un espacio a la izquierda y le agrega 2 asteriscos, mantiene el asterisco en el centro, para eso pone el 1 y con la multiplicacion de la condicion se asegura de que deben agregarse maximo dos más por fila.

si tu quisieras cambiar la cantidad de asteriscos que se le agregan por fila solo seria cambiar el 2 por otro valor y veras que solo al pintar los asteriscos se van a gregando, aun que se ve un poco desordenado por los espacios, solo es para que veas que cosa puede hacer ese 2.

Nota: use letras X, pero pueden ser interpretadas como *

Comment: Muchas gracias me costo mucho entenderlo practimente estos tres dias, es mas facil verlo graficado como un algoritmo para entender parte por parte realmente me sirvio mucho ya que estoy trabado con esta parte hace un monton. Gracias